# ResultSet возвращает неверное время из DATETIME

Tags: java, mysql

ResultSet возвращает неверное время из DATETIME. При извлечении значения времени количество часов увеличивается на 3, т.е. если в бд хранится 15-3, то вернет 18-30.
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: У вас где-то теряется часовой пояс. Например, при записи Вы берете локальное время, но сохраняете его как UTC, а при чтении преобразовываете получаемое UTC в локальное время. Для московского часового пояса как раз три часа разницы и получится.

Comment: Проверьте часовые пояса на компьютере, с которого идет запрос, и на сервере БД. А также тип данных, который используется. Я про 'timestamp with time zone' и 'timestamp without timezone'.